# Accessing Dell server iDRAC console (jnlp) through multiple proxies on Linux

Tags: proxy, linux-networking, drac, socks

I have a server where SSH by root is disabled and SSHing in with LDAP credentials just hangs after receiving the MOTD. Specifically the step it hangs on: `debug1: pledge: proc`

I'm trying to access the iDRAC console now but this server is behind two different proxy hops. On my Ubuntu machine I have a SOCKS proxy configured that puts me out onto the proper LAN, I used this proxy with my web browser to get to the iDRAC webpage in the first place. The command is `ssh -D 9988 -C -q -N $HOST` where $HOST is an SSH config entry I have that hops across two bastion hosts. I don't think there's an issue with my SSH command as I use it all the time for my browser socks proxy (though I imagine the case could be made I should be using the `-J` flag) I just wanted to include it to confirm for you all I'm using the right port.

**The problem:** When I download the .jnlp file, attempting to use icedtea-8 with a proxy  configured correctly(I believe) just gives me a network connectivity error:

```
The host of https://$IDRACURL:443/software/avctKVMIOLinux64.jar file seems down, or you are simply offline.
You are trying to get resource https://$IDRACURL:443/software/avctVMAPI_DLLLinux64.jar but it is not in cache and could not be downloaded. Attempting to continue, but you may expect failure
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
```

IcedTea Proxy settings I've tried:
[Socks: 127.0.0.1:9988](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NmaS.png) I've also tried "use the same proxy server for all protocols, localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, plugging in the localhost:9988 (and 127.) info into all the proxy server settings. I've even set my default browser to firefox and used the firefox SOCKS proxy profile as the default then checked the, "use browser settings" option with no dice.

Is there something obvious I'm missing in using IcedTea over a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: Dear Gawd, that's insane. Where is your VPN?!

Comment: I don't want to go into it too deeply without giving away the agency I work for but it gets worse. Right now with COVID I'm working from home with a site-to-site VPN to our corporate offices, we have a site-to-site VPN from there to the government entity we contract for, inside that LAN we have a NATted LAN (which is where this iDRAC is) but we also have two smaller separate testbed LANs inside this that which are mockups of the the network we're building equipment for. So: HOMELAN -> LAN0 -> LAN1 -> LAN2(iDRAC) SOCKS PROXY goes VPN-d HOMELAN -> LAN1 ->LAN2. It's a nightmare

Comment: I was never able to get this to work with IcedTea on my Linux machine. What I wound up doing was RDPing into a windows machine we host on that network for other purposes. From there I could just open a browser to access the iDRAC web UI.

Comment: Gawd, I'll be glad when we all have IPv6 and insanity like this can start to go away.